# ¿Cómo generar una fecha aleatoria entre 2 rangos en Python?

Tags: python, random

Estoy para generalización de unas pruebas estoy necesitando generar una fecha aleatoria entre 2 rangos de fechas dados, no se me ocurre una manera eficiente mas que acumular muchos if/else usando varias llamadas a randint.

Comment: Lo mas facil seria: Calcular la diferencia (en segundos x ejemplo, depende la granularidad que quieras), luego crear un numero aleatorio en ese rango y sumarlo a la fecha inicial.

Comment: ¿Python 2 o Python 3? ¿Y como ingresas las fecha límites? Si es mediante una cadena, ¿con que formato?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Si usas Python 3.x** puedes hacerlo muy simple usando [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

  ```
  import random
  from datetime import datetime

  inicio = datetime(2017, 1, 30)
  final =  datetime(2017, 5, 28)

  random_date = inicio + (final - inicio) * random.random()

  print(random_date)
  ```
- **Si usas Python 2.7** dado que no soporta operaciones entre `timedelta` y `float` podemos usar `timedelta.total_seconds()` para solucionar el problema:

  ```
  import random
  from datetime import datetime, timedelta

  inicio = datetime(2017, 1, 30)
  final =  datetime(2017, 5, 28)

  random_date = inicio + timedelta(seconds= int((final - inicio).total_seconds() * random.random()))

  print(random_date)
  ```

Salidas de ejemplo:

> 2017-02-28 03:37:36.825489
>
> 2017-04-20 13:50:40.700460
>
> 2017-05-04 18:19:15.100107
>
> 2017-02-22 11:17:24.880618
>
> 2017-03-28 08:32:41.075727
>
> 2017-05-07 11:52:06.075050
>
> 2017-04-29 04:32:03.593637

Simplemente obtienes la diferencia entre ambas fechas (timedelta) y la multiplicas por la salida de `random.random` (float entre 0 y 1). Con esto obtienes un rango de tiempo aleatorio que solo tienes que sumar a la fecha de inicio.

Puedes ingresar la fecha en forma de cadena y con cualquier formato ('30/05/2017')  y también puedes obtener la salida como quieras usando [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) y [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```
def get_rnd_date(start, end, fmt):

  s = datetime.strptime(start, fmt)
  e = datetime.strptime(end, fmt)

  delta = e - s

  return s + timedelta(days=(random.random() * delta.days))


get_rnd_date("01/01/2017", "01/02/2017", "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Esta rutina simplemente genera días aleatorios entre las diferencia (en días) del rango solicitado. No genera horas aleatorias solo fechas, lo cual puede ser positivo si solo querés éstas por que entonces la distribución será más uniforme. De cualquier forma en el sitio en inglés hay [una propuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553303/generate-a-random-date-between-two-other-dates) más completa que tal vez te sirva.