# Modificar celdas especificas de un Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe traido desde excel y es un arreglo de 800 filas y 2 columnas donde la primera columna es un encabezado de formato fecha, es decir tengo una columna con valores numéricos.

Lo que necesito es que se agregue una columna de mas con valores binarios que cumpla la siguiente condición: si hay 5 valores consecutivos mayores a 0,5 imprimir '1' y si no imprimir '0' y que llene todos los datos hasta terminar la columna, además me gustaría que despues me arrojara todas las fechas en las que imprimio el número 1

muchas gracias y quedo pendiente

este es el avance que tengo necesito que me modifique celda por celda de la columna nueva y no toda

```
import pandas as pd

xls = pd.ExcelFile('analisis.xlsx')
dfp = xls.parse('Niño34', index_col = 0)
r = dfp['Niño 3,4'].tolist()
i = 4

while i < len(r):
    a = r[i]
    b = r[i-1]
    c = r[i-2]
    d = r[i-3]
    e = r[i-4]
    if (a > 0.5 and b > 0.5 and c > 0.5 and d > 0.5 and e > 0.5):
        dfp['Niño'] = 1
    else:
        dfp['Niño'] = 0
    i = i+1
```

y así lo tengo en excel y es lo que necesito:
[image: Excel]

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo que buscas es `pandas.Series.rolling`. Una vez generadas las ventanas de 5 elementos basta con aplicar una función que reciba el array/serie con los datos de cada ventana y comprobar si son todos mayores de 0.5:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

data = io.StringIO("""\
Fecha;Niño 3,4
ene-50;-1.62
feb-50;-1.20
mar-50;0.35
abr-50;0.53
may-50;1.31
jun-50;1.25
jul-50;2.30
ago-50;4.35
sep-50;1.20
oct-50;0.23
nov-50;1.40
dic-50;2.30
ene-51;1.23
feb-51;0.54
mar-51;0.98
abr-51;-1.22               
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, delimiter=";")

def app_func(window):
    return (window > 0.5).all()

df["5 consecutivos > 0.5"] = (df["Niño 3,4"]
    .rolling(5)
    .apply(lambda window: (window > 0.5).all(), raw=False)
    .astype("Int8")
    )
```

> ```
> >>> df 
>      Fecha  Niño 3,4  5 consecutivos > 0.5
> 0   ene-50     -1.62                   NaN
> 1   feb-50     -1.20                   NaN
> 2   mar-50      0.35                   NaN
> 3   abr-50      0.53                   NaN
> 4   may-50      1.31                     0
> 5   jun-50      1.25                     0
> 6   jul-50      2.30                     0
> 7   ago-50      4.35                     1
> 8   sep-50      1.20                     1
> 9   oct-50      0.23                     0
> 10  nov-50      1.40                     0
> 11  dic-50      2.30                     0
> 12  ene-51      1.23                     0
> 13  feb-51      0.54                     0
> 14  mar-51      0.98                     1
> 15  abr-51     -1.22                     0
> ```

Si quieres obtener las fechas en las que la nueva columna es 1, basta con aplicar un filtro boleano:

```
fechas = df["Fecha"].loc[df["5 consecutivos > 0.5"] == 1]
```

> ```
> >>> fechas
>
> 7     ago-50
> 8     sep-50
> 14    mar-51
> Name: Fecha, dtype: object
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurrió solución un poco rebuscada.

**1)** Crear una `lista` en la que puedes guardar el `index` del `DataFrame`.

**2)** Guardar en la `lista` cada vez que la condición se cumpla.

**3)** Preguntar si la longitud (`len`) de la `lista` es igual a 5.

**4)** Iterar por cada `item` de la `lista` y grabar 1 en su posición correspondiente.

**5)** Eliminar el primer elemento de la `lista` con `.pop(0)` (con eso nos aseguramos que puedan haber más de 5 consecutivos).

**6)** Resetear la `lista` cada vez que no se cumpla la condición.

Para poder simular tu `DataFrame` me ayudé [generando fechas aleatorias](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/74540/117155) gracias a [@FJSevilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15089/fjsevilla) Senpai.

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from datetime import datetime

inicio = datetime(2020, 1, 30)
final =  datetime(2020, 5, 28)

random_date = inicio + (final - inicio) * random.random()

dias = [inicio + (final - inicio) * random.random() for _ in range(20)]
valores = [0.6,0.51,0.8,0.7,0.9,1,0.1,0.3,3,5,1,5,1,0,4,1,0.6,0,-1,-0.5]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(dias,valores)),columns=['fecha','ninio'])

El algoritmo horroso quedaría asi:


contar = []
df['new_column'] = 0
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['ninio'] > 0.5:
        contar.append(index)

        if len(contar) == 5:

            for item in contar:

                if df.loc[item,'new_column'] != 1:

                    df.loc[item,'new_column'] = 1

            contar.pop(0)
    else:
        contar = []
```

y la salida que obtuve fue:

```
    fecha                       ninio   new_column
0   2020-04-17 13:47:36.639776  0.60    1
1   2020-02-09 23:30:49.155940  0.51    1
2   2020-04-27 13:15:25.427256  0.80    1
3   2020-01-31 08:17:30.401626  0.70    1
4   2020-04-22 01:03:10.578312  0.90    1
5   2020-03-19 10:32:05.345327  1.00    1
6   2020-03-10 09:17:52.448104  0.10    0
7   2020-04-17 07:03:28.607847  0.30    0
8   2020-03-27 12:14:38.890550  3.00    1
9   2020-02-19 10:12:19.870535  5.00    1
10  2020-02-16 01:07:35.363497  1.00    1
11  2020-04-30 06:07:32.967702  5.00    1
12  2020-02-06 21:07:06.706410  1.00    1
13  2020-04-20 11:33:56.425370  0.00    0
14  2020-04-15 20:15:09.887755  4.00    0
15  2020-05-08 11:04:02.193202  1.00    0
16  2020-05-15 22:42:19.291214  0.60    0
17  2020-03-06 23:43:39.081520  0.00    0
18  2020-02-26 02:08:15.930751  -1.00   0
19  2020-04-30 20:05:00.672533  -0.50   0
```

Espero que te sirva y ojalá lluevan mejores respuestas utilizando al máximo la utilidad de `pandas`